# How to determine if my SqlServer version+Edition support partitioning

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning

SqlServer Standard made partitioning available from 2016SP1.  Is there a query I could run to determine whether partitioning is supported on the SqlServer I currently have installed?

I can query the version and edition as well as extrapolate the ServicePack number.  However, I don't want to hard-code the version numbers into the code.  I want to avoid having to distribute a fix should a new service pack be provided for 2016-Standard.

Thanks

Comment: IF you write SELECT @@Version you can see it ? What else do you need?

Comment: I have conditional code for when I can utilize partitions.  the issue with @@Version is that I need to keep a list of the supported version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below checks to see if 1) the edition supports table partitioning or 2) the SQL version is SQL 2016 SP1 or later.

```
IF 
       CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS varchar(30)) LIKE 'Enterprise%'
    OR CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS varchar(30)) LIKE 'Developer%'
    OR CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(30)), 4) AS int) > 13 --SQL 2017 and later
    OR (
            CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(30)), 4) AS int) = 13 --SQL 2016
        AND CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(30)), 2) AS int) >= 4001) --SP1 or greater
BEGIN
    PRINT 'partitioning supported'
END;
```

I see you mentioned not hard-coding version numbers but this method will not require changing the code since the product version and build numbers are incremental.

Comment: That's similar to what I had.  My concern was with 2008 and 2008R2, they went from 10.0.5000.0 to 10.50.1000.0.  They dropped the build number.  But for 2016 they shouldn't be doing that again.  Thanks.

Comment: You are right that the build number could drop when a minor version is released. The could be beefed up to evaluate the minor version for SQL 2016 but that's probably more trouble than it's worth for your use case. Now that SQL Server 2017 is released, I don't see Microsoft releasing a minor upgrade to an older product version.

Comment: There's also sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features.  But I can't confirm I'll get the required permissions on the customer side.  Which is why I have to base it on what's always available.

Comment: `sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features` will only return features actually used that may vary by SKU. Unfortunately, there's no DMV that will return features available for the particular version and edition.